# Using Webcam with Yolov5 Models

Tags: python, opencv, webcam, yolov5, roboflow

I tried to run the example [infer-simple.py](https://github.com/roboflow-ai/roboflow-api-snippets/blob/main/Python/webcam/infer-simple.py), but I can't succeed, because the code is returning a None value when the command line (image = cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)) is executed.

1. code:

```
def infer():
    # Get the current image from the webcam
    ret, img = video.read()

    # Resize (while maintaining the aspect ratio) to improve speed and save bandwidth
    height, width, channels = img.shape
    scale = ROBOFLOW_SIZE / max(height, width)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (round(scale * width), round(scale * height)))

    # Encode image to base64 string
    retval, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', img)
    img_str = base64.b64encode(buffer)

    # Get prediction from Roboflow Infer API
    resp = requests.post(upload_url, data=img_str, headers={
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }, stream=True).raw

    # Parse result image
    image = np.asarray(bytearray(resp.read()), dtype="uint8")
    image = cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    
    return image
```

Always before the imdecode image is array not None, bellow is displayed one debug example.

2. Debug

```
resp: <urllib3.response.HTTPResponse object at 0x0000015055DE7070>

image: array([ 11, 214,  13, ..., 170,   1,   3], dtype=uint8)
```

However, when I run cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)) I get a none value for image.

3.Error

```
Exception has occurred: error OpenCV(4.6.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\loadsave.cpp:816: 
error: (-215:Assertion failed) !buf.empty() in function 'cv::imdecode_'

  File "C:\Users\diego\codes\Webcam\infer-simple.py", line 48, in infer
    image = cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
  File "C:\Users\diego\codes\Webcam\infer-simple.py", line 63, in <module>
    image = infer()
```

I did it all step by step according to https://blog.roboflow.com/python-webcam.

I applied solutions found on the Internet and also reinstalled all necessary packages but nothing worked.

Comment: you may have common mistake - you don't check `if ret:` or `if img is not None` so you try to run code when `frame = None`

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: this tutorial sends image to special portal `roboflow.com` and you can't send it to local server. You would have to first create and run own local server for this.

Comment: now I see you have problem with data from server, not from webcam. Maybe first check what you get in response `resp` without `.raw`. Maybe it sends information that you used wrong `API key`. Did you register on this page to get API key?

Comment: code works for me after registering on server, training some model on server, and getting `model_name/model_version` and `API key` from server. If I don't use it then `resp.read()` gives string like `b'{"message":"Not Found"}'` or `b'{"message":"Forbidden"}'` instead of image

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help.

For the `upload_url` did you put your local host or did you leave it from the server?

Because that was the only different thing I did, I really don't know why it doesn't work here.

Comment: I can't use local host because I don't have local server for this - I used `https://detect.roboflow.com/`. And if you want to use local host then first you have to create this server (write code) and run it.

Comment: BTW: on roboflow.com I created project and trained model with name `chess-sample-cpuhx/1` and got API KEY like `tE7xxxxxxxxx` - so I have full url `https://detect.roboflow.com/chess-sample-cpuhx/1?format=image&stroke=5&api_key=tE7xxxxxxxxx`

Comment: Works now!!  In the source code is the following sequence for the upload_url:  
`"https://detect.roboflow.com/", ROBOFLOW_MODEL, "?api_key=", ROBOFLOW_API_KEY, "&format=image", "&stroke=5"`. When I followed in the sequence you said the code worked. Thank you very much for your help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is not when you get image from camera but when you get image from server.

You have to create project on roboflow.com and gets model's name and api key - and use all this to create correct url.

I created project and trained model with name `chess-sample-cpuhx/1` and got API KEY like `tE7xxxxxxxxx` so I have full url

```
https://detect.roboflow.com/chess-sample-cpuhx/1?format=image&stroke=5&api_key=tE7xxxxxxxxx
```

---

My code with few changes.

I check

- if webcam gives image
- if server send response status `200` and if status is different then display message from server - like `b'{"message":"Not Found"}'` or `b'{"message":"Forbidden"}'`

```
# all `import` at the beginning
import json
import base64
import cv2
import numpy as np
import requests
import time

# --- constants ---  

ROBOFLOW_API_KEY = 'tE7xxxxxxxxx'
ROBOFLOW_MODEL = 'chess-sample-cpuhx/1'
ROBOFLOW_SIZE = 400

# --- functions ---

params = {
    "api_key": ROBOFLOW_API_KEY,
    "format": "image",
    "stroke": "5"
}

headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
}

url = f"https://detect.roboflow.com/{ROBOFLOW_MODEL}"


def infer(img):
    # Resize (while maintaining the aspect ratio) to improve speed and save bandwidth
    height, width, channels = img.shape
    scale = ROBOFLOW_SIZE / max(height, width)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (round(scale * width), round(scale * height)))

    # Encode image to base64 string
    retval, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', img)
    img_str = base64.b64encode(buffer)

    # Get prediction from Roboflow Infer API
    response = requests.post(url, params=params, data=img_str, headers=headers, stream=True)
    data = response.raw.read()
    
    #print(response.request.url)
    
    if not response.ok:
        print('status:', response.status_code)
        print('data:', data)
        return
    
    # Parse result image
    image = np.asarray(bytearray(data), dtype="uint8")
    image = cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

    return image

# --- main ---

video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:

    start = time.time()

    ret, img = video.read()
    
    if ret:
        
        image = infer(img)
        
        if image is not None:
            cv2.imshow('image', image)
        
            if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):  # `waitKey` should be after `imshow()` - to update image in window and to get key from window
                break
        
            end = time.time()
            print( 1/(end-start), "fps")  # print() automatically add space between elements - you don't need space in "fps"
        
# - end -

video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: You put a lot of effort to clarify this question +1